# Visualizing RGB bands of RGBN image

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, python-imaging-library, rgb, image-scaling

I have an RGBN band .tif satellite image of PlanetScope which I would like to preprocess for a neural network. When I view the image in QGIS I get a nice RGB image, however when importing as a numpy array the image is very light. Some information on the image:

```
Type of the image :  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Shape of the image : (7327, 7327, 5)
Image Height 7327
Image Width 7327
Image Shape (7327, 7327, 5)
Dimension of Image 3
Image size 268424645
Maximum RGB value in this image 65535
Minimum RGB value in this image 1
```

The image is uint16 type. The last band (pic[:,:,5]) only shows a singular value (65535) in all instances. Hence, I think this band should be removed leaving the RGBN bands, of which the information is as follows:

```
Type of the image :  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Shape of the image : (7327, 7327, 4)
Image Height 7327
Image Width 7327
Image Shape (7327, 7327, 4)
Dimension of Image 3
Image size 214739716
Maximum RGB value in this image 19382
Minimum RGB value in this image 1
```

The maximum value (19382) of the RGBN image seems pretty low knowing that the range of uint16 images is 0-65535. Subsequently the function 'skimage.io.imshow(image)' shows a nearly white image. I do not understand why QGIS is able to show the image properly in real color but python does not.

The image is loaded by means of `pic = skimage.io.imread("planetscope_20180502_43.tif")`

I have tried scaling the image with `img_scaled = pic / pic.max()` and converting it to uint8 before viewing the image with `img_as_ubyte(pic)` without success. I view the image with `skimage.io.imshow(pic)`.

If necessary the image can be downloaded [here](https://www9.zippyshare.com/v/QNv6Alfy/file.html). I incorporate the image because somehow it seems not possible to import the image using certain packages (Tifffile for example does not work on this tif file).

Comment: Some minimal code that you used to load the image, please. Also – while you are editing that in –, just one question at a time. (I would recommend to remove the "Furthermore …. *very broad discussion*" part, but suit yourself.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited the original question! If there is more information missing please let me know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to be more indicative of what the question is about — you’ll likely get more visitors to your question. “Image processing” is very generic and is also the name of one of your tags. Try to come up with a title that doesn’t duplicate info from the tags.

Comment: Title is edited, I will keep your suggestions in mind for future posts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max values of the RGB channels are lower than that of the N channel:

```
>>> pic.max(axis=(0,1))
array([10300,  7776, 11530, 19382, 65535], dtype=uint16)
```

But look at the mean values of the RGB channels: they are much smaller than max/2:

```
>>> pic.mean(axis=(0,1))
array([  439.14001492,   593.17588875,   542.4638124 ,  3604.6826063 ,
   65535.        ])
```

You have a high dynamic range (HDR) image here and want to compress its high range to 8 bits for displaying. A linear scaling with the maximum value won't do as the highest peaks are an order of magnitude higher than the average image values. Plotting the histogram of the RGB values:

[image: Histogram of RGB data]

If you do a linear scaling with some factor that's a bit above the mean and just disregard clipping the rest (now overexposed) values you can display it to see you have valid data:

```
rgb = pic[..., :3].astype(np.float32) / 2000
rgb = np.clip(rgb, 0.0, 1.0)
```

But to get a proper image, you will need to look into what the camera response of your data is, and how these HDR images are usually compressed into 8 bits for displaying (I'm not familiar with satellite imaging).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you w-m, I was able to built on that and figured it out. Since w-m already did a neat job to elaborate on the problem, I will just leave the code here that I wrote to resolve the issue:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    min_ = int(np.percentile(image[:,:,i],2))
    max_ = int(np.percentile(image[:,:,i],98))

    np.maximum(image[:,:,i])
    np.minimum(image[:,:,i])

    image[:,:,i] = np.interp(image[:,:,i], image[:,:,i].min(), image[:,:,i].max(), (0,255))

image_8bit_scaled = skimage.img_as_ubyte(image)
```